# Not able to draw line on image using Action class

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I tried with different version of selenium. following is the code.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='imageViewer']"));
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);  
    builder.moveToElement(element, 785,322);
    builder.clickAndHold();
    builder.moveToElement(element, 1130, 261);
    builder.clickAndHold();
    builder.build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
```

It draw the line on the image but do not release the mouse so it does not save the line.

Comment: need to call the release() method before perform() call to release the left mouse button

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the release() method to before perfrom(). Refer this [link](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#release--)

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='imageViewer']"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);  
builder.moveToElement(element, 785,322);
builder.clickAndHold();
builder.moveToElement(element, 1130, 261);
builder.release();
builder.perform(); //no need to call build() directly call perform()
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Comment: It did not work :( . I can see the line but whenever it releases the line disappears. Same thing is happening with the robort class as well. Dont know what is wrong.